# Pulled a collection to a custom page on Shopify but no information is showing except images

Tags: collections, shopify, liquid, product

I am looking for a solution to my problem. I am trying to pull a product collection to my unique page in `Shopify` using `.liquid`. I have managed to pull the correct collection and display it in rows but no extra information is showing such as price or title or details. Here is the code I have used to pull the collection onto my page. Any suggestions?

Any information will help! I am also having issues centering this on my page.

```
{% assign collection = collections.aaron-wallis %}
  {% assign products = collections.aaron-wallis.products %}
    {% capture new_row %}
<div class="product_row">
    {% endcapture %}
    {% for product in products limit: limit %}
       <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" title="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
           <img {% if settings.align_height %} 
               style="height:{{ settings.collection_height }}px"
                {% endif %} 
               src="{{ product.featured_image|product_img_url: 'large' }}" 
               alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}" />
       </a> 
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: What is `limit` value and how is it defined? Try `{% assign products = collection.products %}`.

Answer (score 0):

You may loop through specific collection products using this:

```
{% for product in collections[yourcollectionhandle].products %}
  {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

No information is showing because the code you wrote is not supposed to display any information other than the image.

Look at this part of your code.

```
 {% for product in products limit: limit %}
       <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" title="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
           <img {% if settings.align_height %} 
               style="height:{{ settings.collection_height }}px"
                {% endif %} 
               src="{{ product.featured_image|product_img_url: 'large' }}" 
               alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}" />
       </a> 
    {% endfor %}
```

It supposed to display only the linked product image. If you want more like product name , price

```
{% for product in products limit: limit %}
       <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" title="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
           <img {% if settings.align_height %} 
               style="height:{{ settings.collection_height }}px"
                {% endif %} 
               src="{{ product.featured_image|product_img_url: 'large' }}" 
               alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}" />
           <p class="product-title">{{ product.title }}</p>
           <p class="product-price">{{ product.price }}</p>
       </a> 
    {% endfor %}
```